# maven axis2 java2wsdl sun.net.util.URLUtil.urlNoFragString error

Tags: maven, apache-axis

While trying to run java2wsdl axis2 plugin using maven, i get the following error

```
[axis2-java2wsdl:java2wsdl {execution: default-cli}]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.net.util.URLUtil.urlNoFragString(URLUtil.java:29)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:292)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:168)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

my plugin in the pom looks as follows

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <className>com.merc.ws.books.BookService</className>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

my dependencies are as follows

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencies required by client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-codegen</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: hi! have you maybe solved your problem. I have same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Try `mvn process-classes` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to run `mvn process-classes axis2-java2wsdl:java2wsdl` and let me know if it helps.

Executing just `mvn process-classes` or/and adding

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>process-classes</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>java2wsdl</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

section ([according to Maksim Sorokin](http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2011/01/13/axis2-maven-servlets-tomcat/)) didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your service.wsdl file is in the right place: src/main/axis2/service.wsdl

Comment: If he is using java2wsdl - it is clear that he is trying to generate wsdl. java2wsdl docs at apache says "By default, the plugin reads the given Java class and creates a file target/generated-resources/java2wsdl/service.wsdl"